# found .auto-deploy: in gitlab-ci.yml but can't find what does it do as it

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

So I've been given a task to create a CI/CD for a new repo. I can use my company ci.yml files to not start from scratch, however, I have found this snippet at the beginning of the file.

```
    image: alpine:latest

    .auto-deploy:
         image: "exampleprojectrepo/infrastructurestuff/master:latest"
```

And I have failed to find what it does.

Is it a common thing for gitlab-ci.yml to have `.auto-deploy`, like for example .PHONY or is it a project-related thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are so-called "[hidden jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/#hide-jobs)".

Any definition that begins with `.` is not considered a job. You can put pretty much whatever content you want inside of there. By itself, it has no effect on the pipeline, but rather, is useful in the composition of other parts of the CI configuration.

These hidden jobs are often decalred in order to use them with the [`extends:` keyword](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/index.html#extends), [YAML anchors](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#anchors), or [`!reference` tags](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/yaml_optimization.html#reference-tags). Usually for the purpose of keeping your CI configuration "DRY".

You might see it used something like this:

```yaml
.prerequesites:
  image: my/image
  before_script:
    - apt install -y foo bar baz

jobA:
  extends: .prerequesites
  script:
    - make install A
```

Notably, the CI yaml schema does not require the keys for a "hidden" job to be valid keys for a job, but they usually are in order to be compatible with `extends:`.